# How to push same configuration lines on to all the routers and switches using any script/tool?

Tags: cisco, switch, router, lan

I wish to a add a couple config lines to all the routers and switches in the network. Instead of longing into each device, can we do this at once using any script or tool? Please note that we require an user name and an RSA(a time varying password) token to login into any of these devices.

Comment: There are tools which do this. If you have SNMP set up on your devices, it may be possible to use that.

Comment: Parallel processing in Expect
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043219/parallel-processing-in-expect

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but when I want to add similar lines to various devices, I connect to each device on various tabs in SecureCRT and then at the bottom there's a window that provides a "chat to all tabs" capability. I use that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pretty straight forward and there are plenty of good options out there to update the config on multiple devices.

However in your situation this is complicated by having to use a multi factor one time password.

If you have a method that allows you to download and upload the config of each device without logging in to each via SSH, perhaps SNMP and tftp/scp then you could download all the config, run a script over  the files to update, then load them back in again.  You would be having to do your own scripting to make that go through.

Longer term I would consider setting up an NMS Linux host with MFA login and pre shared keys for SSH to run these kind of scripted config changes.